# New NVIDIA geforce 750 Ti. No icon launcher, no top display

Tags: drivers, nvidia

The title pretty much says it all. I've tried installing different drivers, enabled unity, and a few other things. When I physically remove the graphics card from the motherboard, it boots fine and everything works. What now?

Comment: I'm using a Geforce GTX750ti and installed a few for others. The nvidia drivers already available in the repositories work perfectly. What Ubuntu release, what nvidia version are you running and how have you try to install them?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS. I currently have the NVIDIA driver number 364 from the repository. Before I installed this driver, I would only get a black screen. A couple of other symptoms: I cannot adjust the size of my open windows, cannot close the windows unless I use alt+f4. Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE-- Zotac, not Nvidia. Sorry for the confusion